# Continuous function between real line and unit circle

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

Let $f : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous map. Show that there exists a point x in $S^1$ s.t. $f(x) = f(-x)$.

Thank you.

Comment: This is actually the Borsuk-Ulam theorem for n=1 http://www.mi.ras.ru/~scepin/elem-proof-reduct.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $f(x)=f(-x) \iff f(x)-f(-x)=0$